# How to use Maps when Object key is also of type Object

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, object, key

**Structure:**
In dataModel, I have a model called product.
Product has a field called Product ID. 
Product ID has 4 fields.

```
Product = {
    ProductID: {
     field1: "abc",
     field2: "kadjs",
     field3: "skd",
     field4: "kas"
    },
    otherfield: "abd"
}
```

**What I have :**
I have a map called productMap where the structure looks like this:

```
{productID : product}

{ 

         {
          name: "xyz"
          client" "abc"
          code: "123"
          type: "kjsd"
         } 

         :

         {
           productID: 
            {
             name: "xyz"
             client" "abc"
             code: "123"
             type: "kjsd"
            }
           other field: "kajdhs"

         }

}
```

**Reasoning**
The reason I want it to look like this is becuase i currently have a list of Products. And I want to be able to search by productID without having to loop through the entire list. 
As the list of products gets populated, I'd like to simultaneously add them to this map.

**The Problem:**
The problem is, if I have a specific productID and I want to check whether it is in my ProductMap, how do I do that? 
lets say I want to check if some product, newProduct, exists in productMap

I have tried using :

```
if (this.newProduct.productID in this.ProductMap){}
```

the above statement doesn't work.

```
The left-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', 'string', 'number', or 'symbol'.
```

Comment: what is `newProduct` and what does `pendingApprovalMap` contain? Not really clear, not at least for me. But anyway, this seems to be a JS question and has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: your `productID` is an object? you need strings/numbers do index an object. i'd recommend to create a "serialized" version of your productID. could be as simple as  string concatenation

Comment: You shouldn't use objects as index. You can use create a string from the attributes of this product id and use a delimiter in that string to separate different object attributes.

Comment: @MarianTheisen, it's saved as an object, yes. how can i make a serialized version?

Comment: ```function serializeId(productId) { return `${productId.name}-${productId.client}...`; }``` and so on

then when you build the object always do `theMap[serializeId(product.productId)] = product`
and to query the object `theMap[serializeId(productId)]` or in your example: 
`if (serializeId(this.newProduct.productID) in this.ProductMap)`